# How to get the current user name on the computer running a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cd, computer-name

This is what I need:

```
@echo off
title H1Z1 Launcher By Grim0
cd C:\Users\%ComputerName%\AppData\LocalLow\Daybreak Game Company\Digests\H1Z1-KingKill
```

That's the part that I tried but it didn't work.

`%ComputerName%` in path should be the user name of the current user.

How to get the current user name on the computer running the batch file instead of the computer name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
title H1Z1 Launcher By Grim0
cd "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\Daybreak Game Company\Digests\H1Z1-KingKill"
```

Comment: or just %USERPROFILE%

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fdf4z7 = The code with %USERPROFILE%
http://prntscr.com/fdf5a1 =that what happens...
same with %USERNAME%

Comment: @GrimDon You should post your entire code in the question.

Comment: @GrimDon What is the location of the files you're trying to delete?

Comment: Its in a folder that located in this place C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\LocalLow\Daybreak Game Company\Digests\H1Z1-KingKill
and what i'm trying to do is to find the username automatically...

Comment: @GrimDon Edited answer.

Comment: @GrimDon If my answer is correct, you can click the check mark next to it.